# Insert table in .docx file using ZipArchive PHP

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I want to create a table in a docx file using PHP and ZipArchive. But it isn't really working.

I have the following .docx file:
[image: Word document template PHP]

I will put the content here using ZipArchive like the following:

```php
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    $my_table = "
    ...
    ";

    if ($zip->open("document.docx") === TRUE) {
        $template_content = $zip->getFromName("word/document.xml");

        $new_content = str_replace("{{ my_table }}", $my_table, $template_content);


        $zip->addFromString("word/document.xml", $new_content);
        $zip->close();
    }
```

I don't know what to put in the PHP variable `$my_table`. I tried a **HTML table** like this:

```html
$my_table = '
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>H1</th>
            <th>H2</th>
            <th>H3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
';
```

Output:
[image: HTML table output from PHP]

I also tried the **Open Office XML Standard**:

```html
$my_table = '
    <w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
            <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
            <w:tblW w:w="5000" w:type="pct"/>
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
            <w:gridCol w:w="2880"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="2880"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="2880"/>
        </w:tblGrid>
        <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="2880" w:type="dxa"/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>AAA</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2880" w:type="dxa"/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>BBB</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
        <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="2880" w:type="dxa"/>
        </w:tcPr>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>CCC</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        </w:tr>
    </w:tbl>
';
```

Output:
[image: Open Office XML standard]

I also tried to create a table in Word, and extract the Open Office XML from that Word-file. But also that gave the same kind of output.

So what would I place in the `$my_table` variable to get a nice table with borders in my output file?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Is there any specific reason why you're trying to use ZIP and Word XML directly? You could use a convenient abstraction library such as [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord). With that, your task can be done quite simply.

Best regards, Andreas

Comment: Does PHPWord have the possibility to read a docx file? I am altering a template.

Comment: According to the [samples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/samples), it should be able to also read from docx files.

Comment: How do I include it without composer?

Comment: PHPWord does not have the feature needed for this question. PHPWord can't place a table into a template.